# Force windows 10 tray icons to be visible

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, icons, tray

I have an issue with a software I wrote (Delphi) that is minimized to Windows 10 tray icon locations. There are two possible locations, one at the end of arrow #1 and another into arrow #2.
When a new application is installed, by default when minimized (and code written to take care of this), it goes to location #2 by default, and some user are confused and thinks the software has crashed (because this is hidden).  My question is simple, is there a piece of code that forcefully put the minimized app icon into location #1 directly without any action from the user ?
C++ code is OK, or Delphi would be very nice.

[image: Image with location #1 and #2 to explain my question]

Comment: This has been asked many times, and the answer is that you cannot control this programmatically, and you shouldn't be able to.

Comment: Also, the area in the taskbar that contains these icons, next to the clock, is called the "notification area", not the "[tray](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030910-00/?p=42583)".

Comment: The reason why there is no API for this is that if there was, every program would use it, and the notification area would become full.

Comment: OK.
So I have not other choice than warn the user when he will do this the first N times.
To me this is so obvious, but I have three user thinking the software was dead.

Comment: Many times, users have problems for which the solution does involves education of the user rather than changes to the software. Often this is much cheaper for everybody!

Comment: It should be noted that, if you use Microsoft OneDrive for a personal account as well as for an Office 365 Enterprise account, you have two try icons. The operation system somehow ensures both tray icons are both visible or both hidden away. There appears to be way. But I am glad there is no public API for that.

Comment: @Günther the app will register multiple icons with the same guid or program id so that the system treats them as belonging to a single app. That's all above board I believe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Absolutely. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand https://imgur.com/a/EDps3Se

Comment: @Mona: Yes, the user can customize his or her icons. That has always been possible (since XP). However, an application cannot (should not be able to) do it programmatically. That's what I was saying.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Sorry, I forgot to put a comment to the image. I'm referring to the article you linked. Microsoft itself is naming this area as the "system tray" for a long time now, so I guess it's correct to call that area as the "tray".